# Iterator and remove() in linked lists in java

Tags: java

I have a linked list which contains data of people and writes it to a file. I want to remove one entry from the list and then write the new list into a file.
I have used iterator, but when I write it to the file, it displays null entries.

```
public void deleteItem(String Iname){
    MailFiling objFile = new MailFiling();
    MailingList obj = new MailingList();
    Iterator objI = list.iterator();
    while(objI.hasNext()){
        Object o = objI.next();
        if(o.toString().contains(Iname))
            list.remove(obj);
        objFile.WriteToFile2(list);
    }//end of while
}//end of method
```

```
public void WriteToFile2(LinkedList list) {

    try {

        String writeFile = new String();
        for (int i =0; i<list.size(); i++)
        writeFile = list.get(i).toString();

        File file = new File("Mailing List 2.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write(writeFile);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();

    } 
     catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post WriteToFile2 method also. And why are you writing to file in while loop, is this really required??

Comment: Can you also show how you initialize and add data to your list?

Comment: System.out.println("Enter code:");
        Scanner g = new Scanner(System.in);
        p = g.next();
        obj.setpostalCode(p);

        list.add(obj);

        objFile.WriteToFile(obj);

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the iterator's [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) method rather than that of the list.

```
Iterator objI = list.iterator();
while(objI.hasNext()) {
    if(objI.next().toString().contains(Iname)) {
        objI.remove();
    }
}
objFile.WriteToFile2(list);
```

Also note that the write method should be called outside of the loop.

**UPDATE**

There's also a couple of problems with your print code. Try this instead.

```
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
      new FileOutputStream("Mailing List 2.txt"), "utf-8"));
for (int i =0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    writer.write(list.get(i).toString() + "\n");
}
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: I have added my writeToFile method in the question. After I made the changes as above, I am still getting null values in my file.
Can you explain the exact reason of using Iterator's remove method?

Comment: It is still creating this [] in my file.

Comment: Make the changes I made the the latter part, then whip out a debugger if you're still having issues. Place a breakpoint at `objFile.WriteToFile2(list);`, and check the contents of the list.

Comment: What does "utf-8" do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `iterator.remove();` instead of   `list.remove(obj);`